# Defining a list class in c++ using variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to define an IntList class using vadiadic templates in c++11, but I'm having a hard time with the syntax and I'm not sure how to initialize the class fields.

My latest version is as follows:

```
template <int...>
struct IntList;

template<>
struct IntList<>{
    constexpr static bool empty = true;
    constexpr static int size = 0;
};

template<int Hd>
struct IntList<Hd>{
    constexpr static bool empty = false;
    constexpr static int size = 1;
    constexpr static int head = Hd;
    constexpr static IntList<> next = IntList<>();
};

template<int Hd, int... Rs>
struct IntList<Hd, Rs...>{
    constexpr static bool empty = false;
    constexpr static int size = sizeof ...(Rs);
    constexpr static int head = Hd;
    constexpr static IntList<Rs...> next = IntList<Rs...>();
};
```

My list class has 4 fields, with the head field returning the first number in the list and the next field returning the "tail" of the list.

I have a "general" case for a list containing 2 or more numbers and 2 base cases for a list containing 1 number and for an empty list, which does not contain head and next fields (the empty list should throw an error when trying to access one of them).

When trying to test my list, the line:

```
IntList<1, 2, 3>::next::next;
```

Gives me the following error:

```
error: 'IntList<1, 2, 3>::next' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
  IntList<1, 2, 3>::next::next;
```

Trying to define the head and next fields as regular (non-static) fields and initialize them inside a constructor also results in an error:

```
invalid use of non-static data member 'IntList<1, 2, 3>::head'
  IntList<1, 2, 3>::head;
```

Which brings me to believe that I should, in fact, define both fields as "static".

Any input on how to define the head & next fields / what I'm doing wrong, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a potentially ambiguous overload situation. `IntList<1>` is going to be matched by both `struct IntList<Hd>` and `struct IntList<Hd, Rs...>` with an empty variadic parameter list. You can completely get rid of the 2nd template declaration.

Comment: Why do you want to do all this???

Comment: You know that there is [std::integer_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), right?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Good point, I'll delete it!

Comment: @Walter homework :(

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, but the whole point of homework is to abuse students, not to provide a normal practical solution.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to declare a type instead of a static member:

```
using next = IntList<Rs...>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c352431021d1c38c)

Comment: Changing the line:
    `constexpr static IntList<Rs...> next = IntList<Rs...>();`
to what you have suggested results in the error:
    `error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
    IntList<1, 2, 3>::next::next;`

Comment: @Alice312: I have just added a demo link.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want, in about half the code:

```
template<int...>
struct ints {
  constexpr static bool empty = true;
  constexpr static int size = 0;
};

template<int I0, int... Is>
struct ints<I0, Is...>{
  constexpr static bool empty = false;
  constexpr static int size = 1+sizeof...(Is);
  constexpr static int head = I0;
  using next = ints<Is...>;
};
```

now:

```
using just_three = ints<1, 2, 3>::next::next;
static_assert( std::is_same<ints<3>, just_three>::value, "{3}=={3}" );
```

tests it.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c70b78b38605893d).